# Python - Brute Force lendo arquivo TXT e gerando uma saida com seis variações da senha

Tags: python-3.x

A função deste código é ler um arquivo txt (vamos imaginar que neste txt tenham duas palavras: Casa bonita e, na outra linha, carro sujo), após ler, é criado um txt de saída (Resultado.txt), com as variações da palavras contidas no primeiro txt(Ex: Casa Bonita, CASA BONITA, casabonita, CASABONITA, etc). Eu consigo gerar estes resultados, mas quando peço para ler um txt que contenha mais dez mil palavras, durante o processo de execução ele trava e encerra, gerando assim a saída dos arquivos que conseguiu fazer a mudança até travar.

Segue abaixo o código.

```
entrada = input('Caminho do txt p/ leitura >> ')

print('Arquivo carregado', '\n')

arq = open(entrada, 'r')
print('>> Processando', '\n')

saida = open('Resultado.txt', 'w')

for linha in arq:
    if linha.strip().strip("\n"):
        saida.writelines(linha.upper().strip() + '\n')
        saida.writelines(linha.lower().title().strip() + '\n')
        saida.writelines(linha.lower().strip() + '\n')
        saida.writelines(linha.upper().replace(" ", "").strip() + '\n')
        saida.writelines(linha.lower().title().replace(" ", "").strip() + '\n')
        saida.writelines(linha.lower().replace(" ", "").strip() + '\n')

arq.close()
saida.close()

print('>> Processo Concluido')
```

Comment: nesse caso, use o ".write" em vez do ".writelines". O método "writelines" de arquivos é feito para se escrever várias strings que estejam dentro de uma sequência - por exemplo, uma lista de linhas de arquivo. COmo uma string é uma sequênca de strings de 1 caractere, por coincidẽncia ele funciona nesse caso - mas consome bem mais recursos. (não deveria travar, mas essa pode sim ser a causa)

Comment: Todas as variações de caixa uma string é o fatorial de seu comprimento por exemplo a frase `mOça boNitA` gera 3628800 de combinações de caixa ou seja consome 3.5 MB de memória. Se faz isso para 10 mil palavras deve estar pressionando a RAM.

Comment: Bem lembrado. Agora imagina o consumo de memória e espaço a ser utilizado no `HD` se tentássemos produzir todas as combinações possíveis de letras maiúsculas e minúsculas das referidas palavras, aliado às restrições de configurações de hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode carregar linha a linha ao invés de carregar o arquivo inteiro e aplicar o tratamento.

note que no snipped abaixo não é necessário fechar o arquivo de entrada
por que o método **with** já gerencia isso automaticamente.

```py
def do_tratamento(line) -> list:
    #Code para cada formato

saida = open('Resultado.txt', 'w')
with open(entrada,'r') as fp:
    line = fp.readline()
    while line:
        saida.writelines(do_tratemento(line))

saida.close()
```